# Filter rows which has at least two of particular values

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements, any

I have a data frame like this.

```
df
     Languages          Order   Machine    Company
[1]    W,X,Y,Z,H,I       D         D          B
[2]    W,X               B         A          G
[3]    W,I               E         B          A
[4]    H,I               B         C          B
[5]    W                 G         G          C
```

I want to get the number of rows where languages has 2 out of 3 values among W,H,I.

The result should be: 3 because row 1, row 3 and row 4 contains at least 2 values out of the3 values among W,H,I

Comment: `df %>% filter((str_detect(Languages, 'W') + str_detect(Languages, 'H') + str_detect(Languages, 'I'))>= 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
sum(sapply(strsplit(df$Languages, ','), function(x) 
           sum(c("W","H","I") %in% x) >= 2))
#[1] 3
```

**data**

```
df<- structure(list(Languages = c("W,X,Y,Z,H,I", "W,X", "W,I", "H,I", 
"W"), Order = c("D", "B", "E", "B", "G"), Machine = c("D", "A", 
"B", "C", "G"), Company = c("B", "G", "A", "B", "C")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strsplit` on `df$Languages` and take the `intersect` with W,H,I. Then get the `lengths` of this result and use `which` to get those which have more than 1 `>1`.

```
sum(lengths(sapply(strsplit(df$Languages, ",", TRUE), intersect, c("W","H","I"))) > 1)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

a tidyverse approach

```
df %>% filter(map_int(str_split(Languages, ','), ~ sum(.x %in% c('W', 'H', 'I'))) >= 2)

    Languages Order Machine Company
1 W,X,Y,Z,H,I     D       D       B
2         W,I     E       B       A
3         H,I     B       C       B
```